# Drupal 7 - Taxonomy terms hierarchy hook function

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, hierarchy, drupal-taxonomy

As you know there is an admin page for setting up hierarchy of terms by dragging it, which can be found on admin/structure/taxonomy/your_vocabulary. Underneath the table there are two buttons "Save" and "Reset to alphabetical". Now I need to interact with those sumbits by using some hook but I've no idea how to do it. I've already tried hook_taxonomy_term_presave() and hook_taxonomy_term_update(), but those are definitely not appropriate. Any ideas how to hook it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do all your stuff by adding additional callback in submit.
e.g:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function hook_form_taxonomy_form_vocabulary_alter(&$form) {
  $form['#submit'][] = 'my_function';
}

function my_function(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // Do something ..
}
```